# Is it possible to achieve the Opera 12 interface with Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, firefox-extensions, opera

Maybe not Chrome, but I read somewhere that it's possible with Firefox and extensions (Someone said that in a comment). Does anyone know what extensions do I need for that? Basically I'm trying to get that left sidebar from Opera 12, with Mail, Notes, Downloads, History. I can't use `opera` because it has been discontinued. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Is there a reason why you need to upgrade from Opera 12?  If you like Opera 12, and it still meets your needs, you could always stick with it.

Comment: but a lot of sites don't work anymore in opera 12

Comment: "But a lot of sites don't work any more in Opera 12." - Really? Not being sarcastic - I still use Opera 12 as my main browser both at home and at work (Dragonfly being one of the main reasons besides incomparable customisability), and besides file-drag-and-drop type stuff, I can't think of any that don't work in it. If I do come across something, I right-click and "open with..." another browser, but that's very rare. Opera most certainly hasn't been "discontinued", as you claim. Give the new Opera (Blink) some time, and I'm sure many of the "old" features will come back.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this extension([`FXOpera`](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/fxopera/)) will be useful for you.

[image]

---

As suggested by @Vinayak [`FXOpera`](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/fxopera/) and [`All-in-One Sidebar`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/) should work for you.

@Vinayak posted the result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, FXOpera along with [All-in-One Sidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/developers) should do it.

Check out the end result [here](http://imgur.com/LUfphHK)

Comment: @Vinayak added the information given by you, thanks!